# Calling a Postgres function from a sql statement gives error

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7

I am trying to call a function in Postgres, from within my sql statement. It gives me a "column xxx not found" error. My SQL code is below.

```
SELECT r.resource_id, r.name, owner.name, r.status,
r.cost, r.display_unit, r.next_available_date, 
geodistance(r.latitude, r.longitude, 41.824, 71.4128) as distance 
FROM resource_item as r 
INNER JOIN base_user AS owner 
ON r.resource_owner = owner.username 
WHERE distance < 100 
ORDER BY distance, r.next_avail_date, r.name;
```

I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: column "distance" does not exist
```

The function geodistance() itself has been tested as an individual statement like the one below and works fine.

```
select geodistance(38.898556, -77.037852, 38.897147, -77.043934) as distance from incident;
```

I am able to get a response if I put the geodistance() function in the WHERE clause, but I don't know how to do the ORDER BY.

I am stuck a bit. I need to evaluate the distance and be able to compare with an input value. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use label as column name in `WHERE` clause in same level query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.one()
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$ select 1 $function$

postgres=# select one() as fooa from generate_series(1,3) where one < 10;
ERROR:  column "one" does not exist 
LINE 1: ...lect one() as fooa from generate_series(1,3) where one < 10;
```

You have to use subquery

```
postgres=# select * from (select one() as fooa from generate_series(1,3)) s where fooa < 10;  
+------+
| fooa |
+------+
|    1 |
|    1 |
|    1 |
+------+
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. This worked like a charm. Thank you.